# Magento problem after data restoration?

Tags: error

Can anyone resolve it. This problem comes after i upload sample data in database and then click on menus in magento frontend.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 1000) + 1' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 1000) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '39' WHERE ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 1000) + 1 ORDER BY `FLOOR((ROUND((e`.`min_price) * 1, 2)) / 1000) + 1` ASC

Trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(811): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php(274): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(158): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price->getCount(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price), 1000)
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getRangeItemCounts(1000)
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(314): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getPriceRange()
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(151): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->_getItemsData()
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initItems()
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/nilus/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml(34): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/blackn...')
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#23 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(33): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#24 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#25 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/blackn...')
#26 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/community/Magehouse/Slider/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(112): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Magehouse_Slider_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#32 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#33 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gss/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one of your extensions isn't install properly. Try disabling `Magehouse/Slider` and reverting from your custom theme to the default.